# Golang: http2: server sent GOAWAY and has a lastStreamID

Tags: go, http2

We're using go1.12.1, as a HTTP client, if server sent a GOAWAY frame, I just wanna know Golang net library supported:

1. http2goAwayTimeout configurable? I can see there's a TODO: configuration in the description, so not configurable now?
2. There's lastStreamId in the frame, does Golang supported to resend the request that StreamId higher than lastStreamId? Is there any configuration?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/http2 has your answers

Comment: thanks mate, I checked the code, but it seems the http2goAwayTimeout was hard coded in 1*time.Second and I didn't find the API to update this value, could you provide the detail information?

Comment: That's how long it waits to close the conneciton **after** sending GOAWAY. What you're probably looking for is [server.IdleTimeout](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/http2#Server).